# Android seeking while streaming video http range header

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, http-range

Have any one implemented seeking while streaming video over HTTP protocol, with range headers?

We have implemented the server using range header for streaming video over http protocol, and its working fine if we play it through chrome browser.

But in android, VideoView and MediaPlayer is able to stream the data. But problem occurs in streaming.

1) When we use MediaPlayer, we can seek only up to buffered video. If we try to seek beyond buffer, it stops playing.
2) We have tried using Vitamio library, but it doesn't allows us to seek. But it starts playing from beginning. (Don't know why)